# How to output parsed JSON to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, json, oop, parsing

I am trying to display a saved cookie in my HTMl. I am getting [Object object], and not the parsed stringfy. I can display the string version of my object when not parsing it, but I need it to display as an example,"lab1 25 25" or something similar. Am i missing anything? I am still new at javascript.

```
function saveButton()
{

    var cookieName = {'Assessment': [new Assessment("lab1", document.getElementById("lab1").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab2", document.getElementById("lab2").value, 25),    
                                  new Assessment("lab3", document.getElementById("lab3").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab4", document.getElementById("lab4").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab5", document.getElementById("lab5").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab6", document.getElementById("lab6").value, 25),    
                                  new Assessment("lab7", document.getElementById("lab7").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab8", document.getElementById("lab8").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab9", document.getElementById("lab9").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("lab10", document.getElementById("lab10").value, 25),
                                  new Assessment("quiz1", document.getElementById("quiz1").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz2", document.getElementById("quiz2").value, 10),  
                                  new Assessment("quiz3", document.getElementById("quiz3").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz4", document.getElementById("quiz4").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz5", document.getElementById("quiz5").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz6", document.getElementById("quiz6").value, 10),  
                                  new Assessment("quiz7", document.getElementById("quiz7").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz8", document.getElementById("quiz8").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz9", document.getElementById("quiz9").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("quiz10", document.getElementById("quiz10").value, 10),
                                  new Assessment("project", document.getElementById("project").value, 100),
                                  new Assessment("exam1", document.getElementById("exam1").value, 100),
                                  new Assessment("exam2", document.getElementById("exam2").value, 100),
                                  new Assessment("par1", document.getElementById("par1").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par2", document.getElementById("par2").value, 5), 
                                  new Assessment("par3", document.getElementById("par3").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par4", document.getElementById("par4").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par5", document.getElementById("par5").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par6", document.getElementById("par6").value, 5), 
                                  new Assessment("par7", document.getElementById("par7").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par8", document.getElementById("par8").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par9", document.getElementById("par9").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par10").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par11").value, 5), 
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par12").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par13").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par14").value, 5),
                                  new Assessment("par10", document.getElementById("par15").value, 5), 
                                  new Assessment("extraCredit", document.getElementById("extraCredit").value, 25)  
                                  ] };





    //var cookieName =  {'extraCredit': [new Assessment("extraCredit", document.getElementById("extraCredit").value, 25)] };
    cookieName = JSON.stringify(cookieName);
    //var cookieName = document.getElementById("lab1").value;

    //var cookieValue = document.getElementById("cookieValue").value;
    document.cookie = cookieName + ";";
    //alert(cookieName);


}


function displayButton()
{

    //alert("display");
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    var cookieString = "";
    var lblMessage = document.getElementById("saveGrade");
    var i;
    cookies = cookies.split(";");
    numberofcrumbs = cookies.length;


    for(i = 0; i < numberofcrumbs; i++ )
    {
        cookieString = cookieString + cookies[i] + "<br />";

    }
    cookieString = JSON.parse(cookies);
     lblMessage.innerHTML = cookieString;

     alert(cookieString);
}
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="gradeCalculator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="gradeCalculator.js"> </script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="gradCalLab3.js"> </script>

<title>ITS362 Grade Calculator</title>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h3> Welcome to the ITS 362 Grade Calculator!!! </h3>
</div>

<div class="main">


<div id = "tables">
<table>

    <caption> Labs </caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab1"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab2"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab3"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab4"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab5"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab6"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab7"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab8"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab9"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input name="" type = "text" id="lab10"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>


<div id = "tables">
<table>

    <caption> Quizzes </caption>
    <tr class: "text"> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz1"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz2"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz3"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz4"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz5"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz6"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz7"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz8"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz9"></td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="quiz10"></td>
    <td>10</td>


</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>


<div id = "tables" >
<table>

    <caption> Exams </caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="exam1"></td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="exam2"></td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id = "tables" >
<table>

    <caption> Project </caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="project"></td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

<div id = "tables" >
<table>

    <caption> Extra Credit </caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="extraCredit"></td>
    <td>25</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
<div id = "tables" >
  <table>

    <caption>Particpation</caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Points </th>
        <th>Possible </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par1"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par2"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par3"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par4"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par5"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par6"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par7"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par8"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par9"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par10"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par11"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par12"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par13"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par14"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="par15"></td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>



</table>
</div>


</div>

<div id= "scale">

<table width="27%" onMouseOver="displayInfo(event, 'gradeWeight');" onMouseMove="displayInfo(event, 'gradeWeight');" onMouseOut="clearInfo();" onClick="clearInfo()">

    <caption>Grade Scale</caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Percentage </th>
        <th>Letter Grade </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>>= 90</td>
    <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>>= 80 but < 90</td>
    <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>>= 70 but < 80</td>
    <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>>= 60 but < 70</td>
    <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>< 60</td>
    <td>F</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<p><br/>
  <input type = "button" id="calculate" value = "Calculate" onClick= "javascript:sumAll()">
  <input type="text" id="answer" size="10"> <br/>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="saveButton" value="Save" onClick="javascript:saveButton()" />
  <input type="button" id="displayButton" value="Display" onClick="javascript:displayButton()" />
</p>
<span id="saveGrade"> </span>
</div>


<div id = "gradeWeight" style = "display: none">
    Labs : 30% <br/>
    Quizzes: 10% <br/>
    Exams: 30% <br/>
    Project: 20% <br/>
    Extra Credit: 5% <br/>
    Particpation: 10% <br/>
</div>




</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide you html code?

Comment: `cookieString` isn't a string. `JSON.parse` returns the original object. You need to loop over the array elements and create DOM elements from them.

Comment: didnt i create a loop over the array in ? @barmar

for(i = 0; i < numberofcrumbs; i++ )
    {
        cookieString = cookieString + cookies[i] + "<br />";

    }

Comment: After the loop you overwrite the variable with `cookieString = JSON.parse(cookies)`.

Comment: You're not setting the cookie correctly. The cookie should be in the form `name=value`. You're just putting the JSON into `document.cookie` without giving it a name.

Comment: Then when you want to use the cookie, you have to loop through `cookies.split(';')`, split each of them on `=`, and find the one whose name before the `=` is the name you want. There are many tutorials on how to save and retrieve cookies in Javascript, you should go read one, I'm not going to try to duplicate them here.

Comment: After you get the cookie, then you have to use `JSON.parse()` on the value, and loop through the `Assessment` property of that result.

Comment: ok make sense, thanks @barmar. I am barely getting my hands on javascript. next week I tackle JQuery. Thanks Again for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my question. Needed to implement the for loop in order to grab the object properties.

```
    function displayButton()
{

    var cookies = document.cookie;


    var cookieString = "";
    var lblMessage = document.getElementById("saveGrade");
    var i;
    cookies = cookies.split(";");
    var parObj = JSON.parse(cookies[0]);    
    numOfArray = parObj.Assessment.length;
    arrayString = "";

    for(i = 0; i < numOfArray; i++)
    {
        arrayString = arrayString + parObj.Assessment[i].name + " = " + parObj.Assessment[i].grade + " " + "/" + parObj.Assessment[i].worth + "<br />";

    }
     lblMessage.innerHTML = arrayString;


}
```